# Unable to select second option of radio button in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

This is what is already selected:

```
<input type="radio" tabindex="0" name="accounts" onclick="populateSelection();" value="MC Credit ***388.37***" checked="">
```

CSS-selector: `body > form > span > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td.walletDispaly > input[type="radio"]`

xpath: `/html/body/form/span/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/input`

This is what i want to select:

```
<input type="radio" tabindex="1" name="accounts" onclick="populateSelection();" value="Savings ***388.37***">
```

CSS-selector: `body > form > span > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td.walletDispaly > input[type="radio"]`

xpath: `/html/body/form/span/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[1]/input`

What I tried till now:

1. `driver.findElement(By.xcode("//input[@name='accounts'][2]"));`
2. `driver.findElement(By.xcode("//input[@type='radio'][@name='accounts'][position()=2]"));`
3. `driver.findElement(By.id("accounts"))`
4. `driver.findElement(By.name("accounts"))`
5. `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[tabindex='1']")`

Comment: Try `By.xpath("//input[@name='accounts' and @value='Savings']")`

Answer (score 0):

Why xpath are not working :

1. **`//input[@name='accounts'][2]`**
2. **`//input[@type='radio'][@name='accounts'][position()=2]`**

   If both of you element has sibling relation then only it works.
   e.g.

   ```
   <div>
       <input type="radio" tabindex="0" name="accounts" onclick="populateSelection();" value="MC Credit ***388.37***" checked="">
      <input type="radio" tabindex="1" name="accounts" onclick="populateSelection();" value="Savings ***388.37***">
   <div>
   ```

   But it seems that you don't have the element in this fashion.
3. **`driver.findElement(By.id("accounts"))`**

   There is no id attribute in your element so it won't work.
4. **`By.name("accounts")`**
5. **`By.cssSelector("[tabindex='1']")`**

   With the same attribute there are multiple element on your page so it is doing action on very first element and you are not seeing it for your intended elements. Could be the same reason for 5th one.

**Solution**:

Make sure you are locating the element uniquely. You need to customize you xpath. Try below solutions :

**By.xpath**

- `//input[contains(@onclick,'populateSelection')][contains( @value,'Savings')]`

**OR**

- `//input[@tabindex='1'][@name='accounts']`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *absolute xpath* use *relative xpath*. For the *HTML* as:

```
<input type="radio" tabindex="1" name="accounts" onclick="populateSelection();" value="Savings ***388.37***">
```

You can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='accounts'][value^='Savings']")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='accounts' and starts-with(@value,'Savings')]")).click();
  ```